# Implementing Immutable Table in SQL Database with Always Up-To-Date View

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, immutability

I am building a 'debuggable-as-possible' distributed system. My ideal is to keep as much of the state of the system immutable so that, if there is an issue with a previous computation, the computation can be debugged inside the previous snapshot of the system's state.

Politically, there is currently some difficulty in taking a dependency on a new database system such as Datomic. Also, we currently use EventStore, but I feel like it isn't a good or convenient fit for the data I'm trying to represent. Therefore, I'm trying to use a T-SQL database to sort of emulate an immutable data store like so -

1) All operations on the 'logical' table (insert, update, remove) are each represented as an entry into an 'immutable' table.
2) For efficiency, the most recent state of the table (that is, an aggregation of all existing operations in the 'immutable' table) is reflected by an always-up-to-date 'view' table.

Ignoring for now the implementation difficulties of 1, I'm wondering how to ensure that the view in 2 is implemented efficiency and simplicity with T-SQL. That is, I want to avoid completely recalculating the 'view' table for each insertion in the 'immutable' table. Instead, I'd like the operations to be constant time with each insert by taking the current 'view' table state and applying the semantics of each insert. On the other hand, I don't want to have terribly complex SQL code or re-invent too much of Datomic to do so.

The question is, what is a good approach to doing both 1 and 2 with a T-SQL database?

Feel free to critique my approach more generally, and / or provide entirely different approaches to this as I'm totally open-minded about solving the initial problem statement however is possible!